# Mb Mini Player for drupal7

Tags: 7

Is there is any modle avaibale for mini player like

```
http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-miniaudioplayer/
```

I want to implement same player on my website

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the players :

1. [MP3 Player](https://www.drupal.org/project/mp3player)
2. [AudioField](https://www.drupal.org/project/audiofield)
3. [jPlayer](https://www.drupal.org/project/jplayer) - I think this is a player that you want.

Comment: I need same look and feel. but jPlayer doesnot provide dat

Comment: Ok. I don't think so you will get same look feel player.